# Issues with OneToOne Field in Serializer in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have model **UserProfile** related with **User** Model via one-to-one relationship.

**UserProfileSerializer** is defined correctly and it  serializes **userprofile** object well.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user','country')
```

But  it gives **error** {'user':['This field is required']} on passing data.

```
>>> s = UserProfileSerializer(data = {'user':1,'country':'YY'} )

>>> s.is_valid()  
False

>>> s.errrors
{'user':['This field is required']}
```

Comment: repr(s) returns <br.serializers.UserProfileSerializer object at 0x3618a50>. I am using DRF 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late to help, and I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but try setting the `user` field in your serializer to use a `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` so that you can represent a User with an ID, or set the `user` field to be `readonly` if you only want to update `UserProfile` things. If you don't want to use a primary key, other relationship fields are [here](http://tomchristie.github.io/rest-framework-2-docs/).

If you change the `user` field to be a PrimaryKeyRelatedField and you want the user data to return as it is now, you might want to make two `UserProfile` serializers - one for write operations, and one for reading. After a `create` or an `update`, you can switch to the read serializer to populate the response.